# Receiving Data from AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post

I have read a lot of Q&As on here and can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong...
Here is AJAX

```
var color = $('#fontcolor').val();
var size = $('#fontsize').val();
var text = $('#imagetext').val();
var fileToUpload = $('#fileToUpload').val();
var placement = $('#placement').val();


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'upload.php',
                data: {color:color, size:size, text:text, fileToUpload:fileToUpload},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    window.alert(data);
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                error: function()
                {
                    window.alert('error');
                }
            });
```

And then php, I am just trying to simply see my data from now, but it shows empty...

```
<?php
$fontSize = $_POST['size'];
echo $fontSize;
echo "Test";
?>
```

I know that data is coming from form, I have tested variables after data is received, but just can't get it to post... I was using FormData object originally, but decided to simplify for troubleshooting purposes... Still nothing, seems very straightforward, but have been on this for a few days now...

Comment: Are you sure you are not able to post ?? or you are not getting response ??

Comment: Does anything show up from `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: By "it shows empty" do you mean that it doesn't show anything at all? If that's the case try doing a network check using the developer console and see if there's any errors

Comment: The jQuery looks good.  The file upload.php is in the same folder and has permissions to access?  What if you try to view upload.php in your browser?  What if you try to run upload.php from a system command line?

Comment: When I post and echo, it just doesn't echo anything. That is what I mean by shows empty. I know upload.php is accessed, because it does echo my test. upload.php is not in the same folder as my javascript file, but if it is echoing does that imply it has access, or no? I was able to post to upload from a separate php file prior to deciding to use ajax, but that php file was in the same folder...

Comment: When I print_r($_POST), I just get

Array(

)

Comment: So it seems the culprit causing the issue are the following ajax parms:   "contentType: false", and "processData: false,"  But I think these are required when uploading an image via ajax. Is it not possible to pass an image alongside other data at same time? I guess I need to do a little more research!

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I might not be able to pass the image alongside the other parameters, though perhaps there is a way I cannot find. Instead, I will pass image to upload.php, then in response return the image path. Then I will have it trigger success function that passes other parameters to another function that modifies the image accordingly. Works for me.